# confusion on drawImage() method coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas

image coordinates always confuses me.so to test this i did a little example.i have an image which is 500x500.i have two canvas and i want to draw the image on the first canvas .the size of the canvas is 500x500.**the canvas is 50 px from the top and 250 px from the left**.the image is not drawn on the canvas.how i can i solve this & please correct me if i am doing any wrong here

there are eight co-ordinates in draw image function **(which confuses me most)**

```
1st=0,start_X of source image;

2nd=0,start_Y of source image;

3rd=500,destination_x of source image;

4th=500,destination_Y of source image;

5th=0,canvas_start_X ;

6th=0,canvas_start_Y;

7th=500,canvas_finish_X;

8th=500,canvas_finish_Y;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYYq9/)

[image: link to image]

code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
#mydiv{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:black;
}
#mycanvas1{
width:500px;
height:500px;
background-color:white;
border:1px solid white;
margin-top:50px;
margin-left:250px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
<canvas id="mycanvas1"></canvas>
<canvas id="mycanvas2"></canvas>
</div>
<script >
function makeit(){
var canvas1=document.getElementById("mycanvas1");
var ctxbg=canvas1.getContext('2d');
var bgImage=new Image();
bgImage.src="bg.jpg";
alert(bgImage.width+" " +bgImage.height);
bgImage.addEventListener('load',drawBg,false);
function drawBg(){

ctxbg.drawImage(bgImage,0,0,500,0,0,,500,500);
}
}
window.onload=makeit;
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the most confusing way of drawing images to the canvas (in the 2d context) confuses you most why don't you try one of the less confusing ways?

```
ctx.drawImage(img,x,y);
```

or

```
ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,width,height);
```

You should also set your canvas width / height properties on the canvas element, not in the css. The css does not change the actual size of the canvas, the amount of pixels used, just the way it "looks", aka is rendered in the browser. You could display a 1x1 pixels sized canvas in 800x600 and it would still be 1 pixel in size.

What happened in your case is that without width / height properties specified it defaulted to 300x150 in size, so only rendering the top left corner of your image scaled up to 500x500 pixels via css.

That's how you want to set the dimensions.

```
<canvas id="mycanvas1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: sorry typing mistake.it should be(bgImage,0,0,500,500,0,0,500,500)

Comment: that doesn't mean that i didn't try other forms.no matter how i try it is not working?? drawImage(bgImage,0,0,500,500) not working either

Comment: it only draws the cloud looking shape of the image on my canvas :/

Comment: @Winchestro.  Actually the extended drawImage is used often in canvas apps.  Its clipping ability is particularly useful when clipping individual sprites from spritesheets.  Its scaling ability is also useful.  ;-)

Comment: @markE I agree, I tried to be funny there. Of course it's useful, just not if you try to figure out how to draw your very first image to the canvas :)

Comment: @user3138436 ah yeah I just spotted another problem in your code, updating my answer

Comment: i decided to make my first game here.and image is not loading. :((

Comment: @user3138436 what do you mean by "not loading"? That's a completely new problem...a new genre of problem...you never mentioned anywhere until just now^^

Comment: ok that works fine now..give width and height using javascript on canvas element.thanks :D

Comment: by loading i meant not showing.sorry if it confuses you

Answer (score 3):

The 3rd & 4th numeric arguments specify the width and height of the area that is to be clipped from the original image.  The 3rd and 4th arguments are used for clipping a subsection from the original image.

The 7th & 8th numeric arguments specify the width and height of the image to be drawn on the canvas.   The 7th and 8th arguments are used for scaling the original image as it is drawn on the canvas.

Think of the extended drawImage like this:

```
drawImage(
    sourceImage,

    // clip a subsection of the original image 
    // starting at clipX,clipY 
    // with the clipped subsection being clipWidth and clipHeight in size
    clipX,clipY,clipWidth,clipHeight,            

    // draw that clipped subsection on the canvas at canvasX,canvasY
    // with optional scaling to scaledWidth,scaledHeight 
    // (no scaling if clipWidth==scaledWidth && clipHeight==scaledHeight)
    canvasX,canvasY,scaledWidth,scaledHeight
);
```

So you can load and draw your image like this:

```
var bgImage=new Image();
bgImage.onload=function(){
    ctxbg.drawImage(bgImage,0,0)
}
bgImage.src="bg.jpg";
```

Since your not clipping or scaling the original image as you draw it to canvas, there's no reason to use the extended version of drawImage.  But the extended version of drawImage would still work if you specify no clipping and no scaling.

This code will draw the entire bgImage on the canvas (assuming the canvas is large enough to hold the full bgImage):

```
var bgImage=new Image();
bgImage.onload=function(){
    ctxbg.drawImage(bgImage,0,0,bgImage.width,bgImage.height,0,0,bgImage.width,bgImage.height)
}
bgImage.src="bg.jpg";
```

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #mydiv{
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    background-color:black;
    }
    #mycanvas1{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid white;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:250px;
    }
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function(){

    var canvas1=document.getElementById("mycanvas1");
    var ctx=canvas1.getContext("2d");

    var ctxbg=canvas1.getContext('2d');
    var bgImage=new Image();
        bgImage.onload=function(){
           var w=bgImage.width;
           var h=bgImage.height;
           ctxbg.drawImage(bgImage,0,0,w,h,0,0,w,h); 
        }
    bgImage.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/bgImage1.jpg";

}; 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
    <canvas id="mycanvas1" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i replaced it with your second example.it is drawing only the cloud shape on the canvas.(a bigger cloud shape);

Comment: i clipped the image from (0,0) to (500,500) then i draw it on canvas (0,0) to (500,500).that should be the logic isn't it.but nothing worked

Comment: I've added example code to my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/274mD/.  BTW, I think your image URL points to a site that displays your image rather than directly to your image (I assume in your test code you're pointing directly to your image instead). :-)

Comment: i gave width and height on the canvas element using canvas.width/canvas.height via JS like @Winchestro suggested.it draws the image perfectly.tanks for all the help :))

Comment: @user3138436. Yes, specifying the width & height of the canvas element itself is a good standard to use.  Setting width/height using CSS will often cause the image to distort.  Good luck with your project!